# OOP PHP function Connect, function Disconnect

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

slowly getting into the world of OOP PHP, currently working on a database class and struggling to close my connection . The error i receive is;

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\class.Database.php on line 34.

Then i receive my own error message, failed to close connection. I believe it is a problem with the variable that i have in my mysqli_close. Any help greatly appreciated. I have tried $this->myconn and $myconn but no success

```
<?php

class Database{

private $db_host = 'localhost'; 
private $db_user = 'c3337015'; 
private $db_pass = 'c3337015'; 
private $db_name = 'iitb'; 
public $myconn;

public function connect(){

if(!isset($this->myconn)){

$this->myconn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

if($this->myconn){
    $this->myconn = true;
    echo "connected";
    return true; 
}else{
echo "failed";
return false; 
}}else{
echo "already connected";
return false; 
}
  }

public function disconnect()
{
if(isset($this->myconn))
{
    if(mysqli_close($this->myconn)) // ERROR HERE
    {
        $this->myconn = false; 
        echo "connection closed";
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
    echo "failed to close connection";
        return false; 
    }
  }else{
    echo "no connection prescent";
}
}

}
```

Comment: your connect method returns true or false (never echo out in method like you are doing either!) you're also setting your $myconn variable as true again you need to reutrn the object.

Comment: This line `if($this->myconn){
    $this->myconn = true;` is setting the varibale to true and hence its braking on disconnect function.

Comment: just put @mysql_connect(($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example you don't need to wrap the `MySQLi` class in anything, since I see here that you're only duplicating the constructor, and `MySQLi::close()` functionality, so I would strongly recommend taking a look at [The MySQLi Object in the PHP Documentation](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot something reaaaally small.

```
$this->myconn = new mysqli_connect("host","usr","pwd","db);
```

You forgot the new keyword